# What programming language uses ' .. ' to denote range

Tags: programming-languages

I remember the language had a for loop:

```
for i in [1..5]
   Do things
End for
```

And also if statements involve keywords if, then, else, endif

My capitalization may be off

Answer (score 1):

The Ada language makes extensive use of ranges. Those ranges are defined as low_value .. high_value. If the "low_value" is greater than the "high_value" then the range is interpreted as a null range.

Ada arrays are defined by providing a name, an index range, and an element type. The index range is allowed to be any range of values of a discrete type. Ada discrete types are integer types, modular types and enumeration types.

The Ada "for" loop iterates over the values of a specified range.

```
for I in 1..5 loop
   do_something;
end loop;
```

Every Ada array has several attributes accessible during run time. One of those attributes is 'Range which evaluates to the index range for the array.

For example, the following program reads a text file and counts the occurrence of each lower case letter and each upper case letter.

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_Io;

procedure Main is
   subtype Upper is Character range 'A'..'Z';
   subtype Lower is Character range 'a'..'z';
   Upper_Count : array(Upper) of Natural := (Others => 0);
   Lower_Count : array(Lower) of Natural := (Others => 0);

   Filename    : String(1..1024);
   Length      : Natural;
   Input       : String(1..1024);
   The_File    : File_Type;
begin
   Put("Enter the name of the file to read: ");
   Get_Line(Item => Filename, Last => Length);
   Open(File => The_File,
        Mode => In_File,
        Name => Filename(1..Length));


   -- Read each character from the file and tally the letters

   while not End_Of_File(The_File) loop
      Get_Line(File => The_File, Item => Input, Last => Length);
      for I in 1..Length loop
         if Input(I) in Upper then
            Upper_Count(Input(I)) := Upper_Count(Input(I)) + 1;
         elsif Input(I) in Lower then
            Lower_Count(Input(I)) := Lower_Count(Input(I)) + 1;
         end if;
      end loop;
   end loop;

   close(The_File);

   -- Print the tally for each upper case letter
   for I in Upper_Count'Range loop
      Put_Line(I'Image & " " & Upper_Count(I)'Image);
   end loop;

   -- Print the tally for each lower case letter
   for I in Lower_Count'Range loop
      Put_Line(I'Image & " " & Lower_Count(I)'Image);
   end loop;

end Main;
```

The program reads the input file a line at a time then scans the input line for upper and lower case letters. The array Upper_Count is indexed by the upper case letters. The array Lower_Count is indexed by the lower case letters. The array elements in each array are of type Natural which is a pre-defined subtype of the type Standard.Integer. Natural has a valid range of 0 .. Integer'Last.
As each letter is identified in a scan that letter is used as the index value into its appropriate array and the corresponding element is incremented.

The two "for" loops at the bottom of the source code iterate through the arrays printing the index value (the upper or lower case letter) and its corresponding count.